# How can I make the footer stop overlapping with the mobile NAV bar? On the mobile view, the NAV bar goes under the footer. Any solutions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have been trying to resolve this for quite some time, but I am able to find the solution.
On the mobile view, the NAV bar goes under the footer. I think there is some kind of mistake in HTML or CSS code. I tried adjusting the values also added many elements on CSS but nothing worked. Please check the codes for me.

```js
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

    burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        //Toggle Nav
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

        //Animate Links
        navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
            if (link.style.animation) {
                link.style.animation = '';
            } else {
                link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 1.5}s`;
            }

        });
        //Burger Animation
        burger.classList.toggle('toggle');



    });


}

navSlide();
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* For footer but can be used for everything*/ 
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none; 
}

body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

nav {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 9vh;
  background-color: #3b9aff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.nav-links li a:hover{
    padding: 14px 22px;
    background-color: #ffba30;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.logo{
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 20px; 
} 

.nav-links{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 30%;    
}

.nav-links li{
    list-style: none; 
}

.nav-links a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.burger{
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div{
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 16px 24px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #b3bae6;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 16px;
}

.footer{
    width: 100vw;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 70px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #3b9aff;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}

.inner_footer{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 100%;
}

.inner_footer .logo_container{
    width: 35%;
    float: left;
    height: 100;
    display: block;
}

.inner_footer .logo_container img{
    width: 65px;
    height: auto;
}

.inner_footer .footer_third{
    width: calc(21.6666666667% - 20px);
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

.inner_footer .footer_third:last-child{
    margin-right: 0;
}

.inner_footer .footer_third h1{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.inner_footer .footer_third a{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 200;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.inner_footer .footer_third li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.inner_footer .footer_third span{
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 200;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}


@media screen and (max-width:1024px){
    .nav-links{
        width: 60%;    
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:760px){
    body{
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .nav-links{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 8vh;
        background: #3b9aff;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }
    
    /*Mistake*/
    
    nav-links{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    
    .burger{
        display: block;
    }
}

.nav-active{
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

@keyframes navLinkFade{
    from{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }

    to{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}

.toggle .line1{
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px,6px);
}

.toggle .line2{
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggle .line3{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px,-6px);
}

@media(max-width:900px){
    .footer .inner_footer{
        width: 90%;
    }

    .inner_footer .logo_container,
    .inner_footer .footer_third{
       width: 100px;
       margin-bottom: 30px;       
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>e-commerce</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/dadb58458c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="logo">
            <h4>First Education</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Work</a>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Projects</a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="burger">
            <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
            <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="inner_footer">
            <div class="logo_container">
                <img src="logo.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="footer_third">
                <h1>Need Help?</h1>
                <a href="#">Terms &amp Conditions</a>
                <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
            </div>

            <div class="footer_third">
                <h1>More Intel</h1>
                <a href="#">Redeem Voucher</a>
                <a href="#">Free Courses</a>
                <a href="#">Redeem Voucher</a>
                <a href="#">Free Courses</a>
            </div>

            <div class="footer_third">
                <h1>Follow Us</h1>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>

                <span>11 th Floor, 15 St Botolph St, London EC3A 7BB, United Kingdom</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following property in your css classname

```
.nav {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
    ...previous properties
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your nav has a min-height of 9vh.  If the footer winds up being more than 91vh, then it'll overlap.

You're footer is also position:fixed and the text is quite long, which makes it likely to exceed that height.  One thing that could work is position:sticky instead of position: fixed if you want the footer to move along with the page.